# slideToggle как отобразить только один блок из списка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не знаю как отобразить только один блок из списка. Писать для каждого свою функцию уж совсем глупо будет. Прошу помощи у знающих людей. Заранее спасибо.

**Вот пример кода**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.operation').on('click', function() {
    $('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
    $('.operation-info').slideToggle(400)
  });
  //next dropdown1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="operation">
  <div class="wrapper-icon">
    <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
  </div>
  <span>text123</span>
</div>

<div class="personal-info-middle operation-info">
  <h3>Ласкаво просимо!</h3>
  <p>....</p>

</div>
```

**Дополнение:**
`.plus-minus-toggle` - класс анимированого  крестика.
`.op.operation-info` - часть выпадающего окна.

Comment: У вас в разметке кол-во открывающих и закрывающих тегов не сходится

Comment: мне честно говоря совсем не понятно чего именно вы хотите добиться

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych   это  обычный  аккордеон,  он работает. Но если  я создам  несколько  таких блоков  в разметке,  тогда  будут  отрываться  все сразу.  мне  нужно  что  бы  открывался только  тот, на который  я  кликаю:)  буду  благодарен  за  любой совет).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно, чтобы текст раскрывался именно в том блоке, где вы кликаете на `.operation`. Для этого этот текст нужно искать внутри того родителя, где и находится `.operation`. Используйте для этого метод `.closest()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.operation').on('click', function() {
    var block = $(this).closest('.block');
    block.find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
    block.find('.operation-info').slideToggle(400)
  });
  //next dropdown1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="operation">
    <div class="wrapper-icon">
      <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </div>
    <span>text123</span>
  </div>

  <div class="personal-info-middle operation-info">
    <h3>Ласкаво просимо!</h3>
    <p>....</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="operation">
    <div class="wrapper-icon">
      <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </div>
    <span>text123</span>
  </div>

  <div class="personal-info-middle operation-info">
    <h3>Ласкаво просимо!</h3>
    <p>....</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="operation">
    <div class="wrapper-icon">
      <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </div>
    <span>text123</span>
  </div>

  <div class="personal-info-middle operation-info">
    <h3>Ласкаво просимо!</h3>
    <p>....</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="operation">
    <div class="wrapper-icon">
      <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </div>
    <span>text123</span>
  </div>

  <div class="personal-info-middle operation-info">
    <h3>Ласкаво просимо!</h3>
    <p>....</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: очень вам  благодарен!   Спасибо!

Comment: @Andriikhmelovskyi Пожалуйста

Comment: Недавно начал учить js,  основы  знаю.  но  на  толковые материалы с  задачками никак  немогу выйти.  может посоветуете книжечку или  ресурс какой то полезный?

Comment: @Andriikhmelovskyi вот тут можно найти примеры на [js](http://learn.javascript.ru/), а тут - на [jquery](http://jquery.page2page.ru)